# Open-source comment engines

Tags: php, open-source, comments, disqus

I'm looking for a solid open-source commenting engine written in PHP.  It needs to have workflow/moderation capabilities as well.

I've checked into Disqus, and while I like the concept, the site owner's may develop their own login system at a later point, which would have to integrate with the comment system.  Also, I'm not sure that they want the comments hosted remotely.

Does anyone have any recommendations that I might look into?  Alternatively, if you have experience with Disqus, what do you like/dislike about it?

Comment: https://github.com/umputun/remark42 it's a very good competitor. It's built by one of the leaders of https://radio-t.com/ which is a very famous Russian podcast. JetBrains started to use it https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2021/04/pycharm-2021-1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Commentator](http://ratherodd.com/commentator/) looks to have a solid community backing, is written in PHP, and has most of the features you'd expect from a comment system.

Comment: What about the open source space ?

Comment: what about 3rd party cookies and 3rd party scripts?

Answer (score 0):

you may want to **check** on to  this site too, here is the **link**:

[Commentics](http://www.commentics.org/)

as the Website itself **Describes** it :

**What is Commentics?**
Commentics is a **free**, advanced **PHP comment script** with many features. Professionally written and with **open source code**, its main aims are to be integrable, **customizable** and **secure**. It is designed to be integrated into your existing pages.

Comment: Can you please comment+format your answer more?

Comment: sorry for my late Edit!:) hope it was helpful...